# Can't see UTM installs on Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, utm

In Google Analytics, under the Acquisition tab, I can see the number of installs each source brought (the Playstore link contains a utm code, as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liquidum.rocketvpn&referrer=utm_source%3Dhuhu1981).

How can I see the same information in Firebase?

[Pic: Example of UTM source installs on Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxkM4.png)

Answer (score 1):

The same URL with the utm code should work for both Google Analytics and Firebase Analytics. You can see the install attribution in Firebase Analytics under "**first_open attribution**" card in Analytics Dashboard or under **Attribution/first_open** event.